# Возврат вектора из функции

Tags: vector, c++, функции

Как правильно возвращать вектор из функции - возвращать сам вектор, указатель на него или итератор? "Правильность" интересует с точки зрения оптимального использования ресурсов и хорошего стиля программирования.

Comment: Передавайте в функцию ссылку на вектор, который вы собираетесь заполнять.

Comment: А если вектор хранится у меня как поле класса?

Comment: Правда, что благодаря оптимизации компилятора RVO (Return Value Optimization), код будет работать быстро, даже если будет возвращаться сам вектор?

Comment: Если вектор является полем класса, то лучше всего возвращать константную ссылку. Так вы дадите пользователю класса выбор: копировать результат или нет.

Comment: Темный гений, про RVO - правда

Comment: два способа уже описали, достаточно хороших способа. Есть ещё третий - завернуть вектор в умный указатель.

Comment: @mikillskegg, в данном случае (вектор является полем класса) это неправда.

Comment: Какой синтаксис возвращения константной ссылки?

Comment: @DarkGenius: `const T&`, конечно. А на что вы собираетесь ссылку возвращать — надеюсь, не на вектор, лежащий в стеке самой функции?

Comment: @VladD,вектор - поле класса.

Comment: @DarkGenius: Если время жизни вектора — не проблема, конечно возвращайте const ref.

Основная проблема C++ и состоит, на мой взгляд, в том, что приходится чересчур много думать об аллокации/деструкции/копировании ресурсов и владении ими. Например, казалось бы, что опасного в конструкции

    v.push_back(v.back());

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте-ка я суммирую дискуссию в комментариях здесь.

Классическим методом является передача пустого вектора по ссылке **в** функцию, с тем чтобы функция его заполнила.

Затем, если вы уверены, что время жизни вектора, который вы передаёте, достаточно велико (например, вектор является полем класса), то вы *можете* возвращать ссылку на него. Внимание! При этом вы вводите потенциально опасную зависимость: если сам объект умрёт, ссылка на вектор тоже перестанет быт валидной! Сам объект не может знать, как его используют, и не является ли он, например, временным.

Затем, вы вполне можете вернуть вектор по значению, особенно если вы конструируете его на стеке в самой функции (и значит, не можете вернуть *ссылку* на него). Это кажется излишним копированием, но на самом деле оптимизатор часто может убрать ненужное копирование используя RVO/NRVO. (Вот ссылкf про это: [NRVO in Visual C++ 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). Тем не менее, иногда эта техника может всё же ведёт к копированию (например, потому, что оптимизатор не волшебник) и показывает [плохие результаты](https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/want-speed-dont-always-pass-by-value/).

И ещё: я бы не советовал возвращать итератор. Итераторы в C++ — ещё более хрупкая вещь, чем ссылки: *любой* чих в сторону вектора может его инвалидировать.

Answer (score 3):

- Возврат **итератора** требует фактического хранения вектора после  завершения работы. Т.е. либо вектор должен быть статичным (объявлен с ключевым словом `static`), либо как член класса, а возвращать его будет метод, либо получен на вход функции ещё откуда-либо.

  С одним лишь итератором многого не сделать: неизвестно, например, сколько ещё элементов после текущего итератора можно прочитать (для этого придётся возвращать пару итераторов, итератор и длину остатка или что-то подобное), нельзя вставить новый элемент или удалить существующий. С другой стороны, итератор концептуально представляет собою позицию в контейнере (плюс вариант отсутствия когда итератор указывает на `end`).

  Итого: если вам нужна именно семантика указателя на позицию в контейнере, итератор вам подойдёт. В остальных случаях ничего хорошего не выйдет.
- Возврат **указателя** можно разделить на 2 случая: с передачей владения и без (т.е. определить, кто занимается удалением вектора).

  - Если владение не передаётся, остаются всё те же требования к времени жизни рассматриваемого вектора, как и в предыдущем пункте. В таком случае можно также вернуть **ссылку** на вектор — подходы будут эквивалентны.

    ```
    class Node {
      std::vector<Node> children_;
      // ...

    public:
      // ...
      const std::vector<Node>& getChildren() const {
        return children_;
        // ОК: возвращаемый вектор имеет такое же время жизни, как
        // и объект, с которым мы работаем
      }
    }
    ```
  - Если нужно передать владение вектором вызывающему контексту, следует изначально создавать его на куче (с помощью оператора `new`). С точки зрения идиоматичного C++ следует использовать умные указатели `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` или их аналоги из библиотек вроде `boost` или `Qt`.

    ```
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> getNumbers(int n) {
      auto res = make_shared<std::vector<int>>(n);
      // ...
      return res;
    }
    ```

    Следует заметить, что в C++11 такой подход довольно бессмыслен, поскольку там существует семантика перемещения (об этом позже). С другой стороны, `shared_ptr` доступен и в [C++03 с TR1](https://anteru.net/2008/09/01/260/). Правда, он может быть не совсем эквивалентен своему собрату из 11 стандарта.
- Возврат **по значению** может вылиться в дорогостоящее копирование, однако:

  - В C++11 (который на текущий момент с нами уже 4 года, между прочим) существует семантика перемещения, которая позволит вернуть вектор по значению без копирования.
  - Даже для более старых стандартов многие компиляторы реализуют оптимизации Return Value Optimization и Named Return Value Optimization (подробнее о этих товарищах можно почитать у [Алёны C++](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2008/02/rvo-nrvo.html)). Несмотря на то, что большинство компиляторов поддерживают эти оптимизации, могут существовать экзотические / старые компиляторы, не проводящие их.

    Следует отметить, что эта оптимизация не всегда срабатывает. Один из таких случаев — когда возвращаемый результат зависит от пути исполнения, например

    ```
    std::string toString(bool flag) {
      std::string a("True");
      std::string b("False");
      return flag ? a : b;
    }
    ```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
void MagicMethod(std::vector<SomeData> &destVector) {
    std::vector<SomeData> tmpVector;

    //что-то делаете с tmpVector ...

    destVector.swap(tmpVector); //вернули вектор
}
```

Comment: Почему бы сразу не работать с `destVector` тогда? К чему лишние выделения памяти?

Comment: В многопоточной среде, если есть обращения к объекту под destVector, придется ставить лок на весь период работы с destVector. А так, можно поставить лок только на операцию swap.

Comment: Также, если destVector пуст, то лишние выделения памяти будут только в размере пустого объекта std::vector<>